# CSS - A menu that reads down then to the right

Tags: jquery, css

I have an odd client request: they want a menu structure that reads down then to the right. Is there any good way preferably using CSS only (a jQuery/javascript solution would work too) to have a menu flow like so:

```
Link 1  Link 4  Link 7  Link 10
Link 2  Link 5  Link 8  Link 11
Link 3  Link 6  Link 9  Link 12
```

The menu needs to be alphabetized and needs to be flexible (i.e. the client can add or remove as many links as they wish). The only thing I could really think of doing is a different unordered list for each column. The only issue with that is the client will need to manually sort the menu items so their even.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: The Column properties is a neat idea. I've played with them before though and support is thin. Way too thin for the minimum browser spec.

Comment: The question is similar but the accepted answer assumes that the column length will be fixed when the client can add or subtract items from the list. Also, I need support for IE7 for this site.

Comment: Thought I'd play with this today and came up with a different approach, just for fun. http://jsfiddle.net/G3WyZ/7/